# SetInterval function argument

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I'm (brand) new to programming and I'm trying to create a simple javascript game.

My questions is:

**Why does the window.setInterval function seem to brake everything?**

I'm learning from [this tutorial](http://dhmholley.co.uk/incrementals.html) and tried to rewrite the whole thing while using different variable names. The original works fine as expected, but as soon I add the last 3 lines of code of javascript, the whole thing becomes unresponsive. I've been looking at this code for 30 minutes and I can't seem to find the problem.

**main.js**

```
var things = 0;
var gen1 = 0;


function thingClick(number) {
    things = things + number;
    document.getElementById("things").innerHTML = things;
}

function buyGen1() {
    var gen1Cost = Math.floor(10 * Math.pow(1.1, gen1));
    if(things >= gen1Cost) {
        gen1 = gen1 + 1;
        things = things - gen1Cost;
        document.getElementById('gen1').innerHTML = gen1;
        document.getElementById('things').innerHTML = things;
    }
    var nextCost = Math.floor(10 * Math.pow(1.1, gen1));
    document.getElementById('gen1Cost').innerHTML = nextCost;
}

window.setInterval(function) {
    thingClick(gen1);
}
```

**index.html**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>
  <body>
        Things: <span id="things">0</span><br><br>
        <button onClick="thingClick(1)">Get Things</button><br><br>
        <button onClick="buyGen1()">Buy Generator Lvl. 1</button><br><br>
        Generators Lvl. 1: <span id="gen1">0</span> | Cost: <span id="gen1Cost">10</span>

     <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Because you typo'd? `setInterval(function() {thingClick(gen1);},1000);` Or whatever interval you want.

Comment: Step 1, look up what `setInterval()` is and how it's used.

Comment: Another note from looking at that tutorial. You want to try and avoid adding JS directly in HTML like `onClick="thingClick(1)"`, instead you want to [add an event listener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) in your JavaScript code.

Comment: The tutorial you are working from has an example of correct usage of `setInterval()`. Compare it with your code. Also, one of your top priorities should be learning how to use the developer tools in your browser. Every browser has them, and they will help you immensely. For example, here is a great [overview of the Chrome DevTools](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setInterval` works kind of like this:

```
var interval = setInterval(function(){
  //call code here every n seconds
},delay)
```

---

a practical example is like this:

```
var interval = setInterval(function(){
   thingClick(gen1);
},2000) //call it every 2000 milliseconds, or 2 seconds
```

So you basically wrote `setInterval` wrong

Also you can stop your interval by clearing it. So for the example above simlpy calling `clearInterval(interval)` will stop it/clear it.

Comment: Yes, thanks for the heads up. I'm gonna google some developer tools to help me debug the code.

Answer (score 0):

## Syntax

When JavaScript finds one error. It will completely stop, your error is in your syntax:

```
window.setInterval(function) {
    thingClick(gen1);
}
```

Should be:

```
window.setInterval(function () {
}, 500); // Adjust 500
```

---

## Flow

The compiler is doing something *like* this:

- Checking `window.setInterval()` with argument `function`

  - The compiler then notices invalid syntax and throws an error preventing JavaScript from running.
- *If the compiler for some reason didn't stop*, It would see some random code in `{}` confusing it more

---

#### clearInterval()

When creating setIntervals, you should always assign it to a variable so you can stop it. You don't want a run-away timer:

```
var my_timer = window.setInterval(function () {
    thingClick(gen1);
}, 1000); // Every 1000 ms
```

Then you can run:

```
window.clearInterval(my_timer);
```

---

Comment: Good explanation, but the description under "Flow" isn't exactly how it works. The JavaScript engine doesn't run your code until it encounters a syntax error. If there is a syntax error, it doesn't run *any* of the code in the same compilation unit (e.g. script tag or file). There is a compilation pass that runs first and checks all the syntax. Only if that pass completes without error does it start executing the compiled code.

Comment: @MichaelGeary I added *like* so I could simplify it

Comment: I'm all for keeping things simple, but why give an explanation that is incorrect when the correct explanation is actually simpler: First, the JavaScript engine checks all of the syntax in a `script` tag or file. If there are any syntax errors, it stops right there, otherwise it begins executing the code.

Comment: BTW I'm being a stickler about this not to be annoying, but because it's so important in programming to have a correct mental model of how things work. Believing things that are almost but not quite correct will get you in trouble sooner or later, so it's helpful to have an understanding that matches how it really works.